# Probability of X lying within one standard deviation for different distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

We know that for the normal distribution (denote this $P_N(x)$), the probability of a random variable having a value within one standard deviation of the mean is approximately $68$ %. That is
$$\int_{\mu-\sigma}^{\mu+\sigma} P_N(x)\approx 0.68$$
This is true for all *Normal* distributions. Similarly, for all *normal* distributions, the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean absolute deviation is
$$R\equiv \frac{\sigma}{MAD}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\approx1.25$$
I will refer to this quantity as the *characteristic ratio* of the distribution and denote it by $R$. I have noticed that for any distribution I analyze, if the distributions characteristic ratio ($R=\frac{\sigma}{MAD}$) is small, then the the probability contained within one standard deviation is small. For example, for the constant distribution $P_a(x)=1/a$, we have that
$$R=\frac{\sigma}{MAD}\approx 1.1547$$
This is less than the characteristic ratio of the normal distribution and so sure enough, if we calculate the probability contained within one standard deviation of the mean, we get a value less than that of a normal distribution (which is $0.68$)
$$\int_{\mu-\sigma}^{\mu+\sigma} P_a(x)\approx 0.577$$
I have tried numerous distributions and always get a higher probability contained within one standard deviation given a higher characteristic ratio and vice versa. Is there a theorem or proof relating these 2 quantities for a distribution? That is, given the characteristic ratio of a distribution, is there a formula that relates the characteristic ratio to the the probability contained within one standard deviation? My second question is: Is there an intuitive way to interpret why a large characteristic ratio implies a large probability within one standard deviation?

Comment: I suspect this isn't true - but I lack the firepower to show it! You can choose from a wide variety of shapes for distributions, I suspect one could find one which didn't match your rule.

Comment: @Blitzer Agreed. Although I did try it with 3 other common distributions and the rule held for them as well. I just didn't show them all to conserve space in my question.